# Android NDK build error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ogre

I get the following errors when I build my android app using the NDK in eclipse(ubuntu):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: SOMEPATH/ogre/build/OgreJNI/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/
libcpufeatures.a: No such file or directory

Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    

make: *** [APATH/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libInMapsJNI.so] Error 1

Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library 
dependencies of the    

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Android NDK:     current module    


..........


**** Build Finished ****
```

The problem is: the App then launches but crashes without giving any error to the console.
Does someone know how I can fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Post your Android Makefile here so we can review it.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty explicit: `SOMEPATH/ogre/build/OgreJNI/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcpufeatures.a` is not a valid path. Are you using a relative or absolute path here?

The App launches because the Java part has no error, but the C++ part (`libInMapsJNI.so`) was not compiled, and therefore the App crashes at runtime when it tries to link this library.